# Does C++ 11 introduce any new ways to break from a nested for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, idioms

Consider a case of a **for** inside an other **for**

```
int f( ... )
{
  for (int i = start_a; i < end_a; i++)
  {
    for (int j = start_b; j < end_b; j++)
    {
      // make some computation
      if( i_must_exit == true)
      {
        // exit from all for
      }
    }
  }

  // I want arrive here
}
```

We want to break from both `for` loops.  This isn't easy in C++03 without factoring out the inner function, throwing an exception, etc. I was wondering if C++11 introduced a mechanism by which to do this.

Comment: `abort();`. I'd do that if I'd be this application

Comment: That's a common case in *bad* code.

Comment: This is taking hatred of "goto" to a new level.

Answer (score 11):

I think the best solution is to use iterators and algorithms, like `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best solution is using a lambda ... something like this:

```
int f()
{
  [&]{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
      for (int j = start_; j < end_; j++)
      {
        // make some computation
        if( i_must_exit == true)
        {
          // exit from all for
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }(); // execute this code now!

  // continue with computation
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't so much using a lambda as almost refactoring the loop into its own function. Give it a good, explicit name as to what it does and you've got yourself some nice separation of concerns. That the refactored code appears in a lambda instead of a bona-fide C++ function a purely syntactic difference. (You might also want to avoid default captures here.)

Comment: @LucDanton I'd drop the `auto L =` and the `()` and leave the default capture.  Then the lambda becomes a control structure that allows you to break out via `return` from anywhere in the inner scope. Actually as written it didn't compile (void lambda cannot have its return value stored), so I made my changes and it now compiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
int f( ... )
{
  bool b = false;

  for (int i = start_a; i < end_a; i++)
  {
    for (int j = start_b; j < end_b; j++)
    {
      // make some computation
      if( i_must_exit == true)
      {
         b = true;
         break;
      }
    }
    if (b)
        break;
  }

  // I want arrive here
}
```

Comment: in this way you are introducing a variable